# Showing a time-series track (moving object) in SVG

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, graphics

I want to display a time series track using SVG in two different modes. One mode would show a dot where the location of the object is at different times, and another mode would show all the locations (every dot).

So, for example, at the bottom of the screen there might be 4 buttons: "Time 1", "Time 2" and "Time 3" and "Show All". If you clicked on one of the times, it would just show where the object was at that time, but if you click on the "show all" button, then all the dots are displayed at the same time.

What is the best way to set this up in SVG? I can draw dots, but I am unsure of the best methods for using Javascript to do animations/hidings like this.

Comment: Consider looking at d3.js, a visualization library made for these kind of problems

Comment: I am familiar with d3. I am using pure SVG.